# Rendering newline in text for a div when working with Flask as the backend?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask

I am using Flask as the backend and reading a piece of text from a file that contains newlines as `\n`. I wish to render this text inside a div. To do so, I am replacing the `\n` with `<br>` and then passing it to the `render_template()` method.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
        content = read_file('filename.csv') 
        content = content.replace('\\n','<br>')
        return render_tempate('index.html',text=content)
```

However, doing so shows the br tag as text. The underlying html shows that the br tag is being interpreted as `&lt;br&gt;`

`<div>some text &lt;br&gt; some more text</br>`

How can I fix this and render a newline inside the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `index.html`, change your `{{text}}` tags to `{{text|safe}}`. By default, HTML strings are escaped in `render_template`, and the `|safe` is needed to turn that off.